# Logical equivalent of $p\to(q\to p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is Logical equivalent of $p\to(q\to p)$, $p\to(p\wedge q)$ or $p\to(p\vee q)$?
I have a truth table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
p&q&p\wedge q&p\vee q&q\to p&p\to(q\to p)&p\to(q\wedge p)&p\to(q\vee p)\\\hline
T&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}&F&T\\
F&T&F&T&F&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}\\
F&F&F&F&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}&F\color{red}{(T)}
\end{array}$$
In red color is actual answer.

Comment: Two formulae are *logical equivalent* if in each row of the truth-table they have the same truth-value. But the truth-table is not correct ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I created the table myself and according to it 3rd and 4th column match but it is not the case with the actual answer.

Comment: I can't understand the question, the english is broken. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Your implications are all off. The only time $p \to q$ is false, is when $(p,q) = (T,F)$.

Comment: @pjs36 False doesn't imply True i.e. $F\to T$ is F and neither does $F\to F$ which then should be F?

Comment: Do yourself (and us) a favor, and add the following columns to your truth table (immediately after the first two columns): ${p}\rightarrow{q}|{p}\wedge{q}|{p}\vee{q}$.

Comment: $F \to \_\_$ is sort of "technically" true. Think of the statement "If it rains, then I'll bring an umbrella." The only time I'm lying is when it rains, but I don't have an umbrella. If it doesn't rain, I didn't lie; I'm off the hook, and it's technically true, whether I have an umbrella or not.

Comment: @barakmanos done.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA redone.

Comment: Well done ! now you can check it two or more (of the three rightmost) columns have the same sequence of truth values ...

Comment: I'm curious...why did you try to use a truth table when logical deductions are both easier and more informative?

Comment: ... or something real live: Given "If I have an apple, then if it rains, I have an apple" Alternative 1 "If I have an apple, then it rains and I have an apple". Alternative 2 "If I have an apple, then it rains or (at least) I have an apple"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding stems from the basic implication connective.

\begin{array}{|c|c | c|}\hline
p & q &p \to q \\ \hline
T &T& T\\
T&F& F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T\\ \hline
\end{array}

Thus, the statement *If $P$, then $Q$* is False only when the premise, $P$, is True, while the conclusion, $Q$, is False.

It's not quite right to think that, because the *logical statement* $F \to \_\_$ is True, then "false implies truth". We simply don't have the logical inference tools to make statements like that.

We have modus tollens that allows us to conclude that, if we know $P \to Q$ and we also know that $P$ is True, we can conclude that $Q$ is also True.

We also have modus ponens that tells us, given $P \to Q$ while $Q$ is False, we can conclude $P$ must also be False (Otherwise the premise would be true and the conclusion false, contradicting $P \to Q$).

So just remember that symbolic logic only goes so far, with regards to interpreting statements like "$0 = 1 \to$ the Riemann Hypothesis." As a logical statement, this is true, but it has no bearing on the truth value of the Riemann Hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

An implication $A \rightarrow B$ is only false, iff $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

So, the implication $ p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ can only be false, iff  $p$ is true and $(q \rightarrow p)$ is false.

The implication $(q \rightarrow p)$ can only be false, iff $q$ is true and $p$ is false. But $p$ is true.

If $p$ was false, then the entire statement $ p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ would be true again.

So, this statement is always true (such statements are also called tautologies).

In order to find its equivalent, we know that $p$ must be true and we must look what expression can never be false, if $p$ is true. This is $ q \lor p$, because it is true, iff either $p$ or $q$ is true. The statement $q \land p$ can become false, iff $q$ is false.

Hence, the equavilent is $p \rightarrow (p \lor q)$.

Answer (score 2):

You should correct your truth table by adding a $q \to p$ column.

From top down it will read T, T, F, T so that $p \to (q \to p)$ is seen to be a tautology.

Comment: does $p\to q$ mean if p is T then q will also be T and nopthing else?

Comment: Informally, it asks if $p$ is true then is $q$ also true? This is false if $p$ is true and $q$ is false, but true in all other cases.

Comment: edited my table,please resee.

Comment: You didn't include a $q \to p$ column.

Comment: redone. umberto P

Answer (score 2):

Using a truth table in this case is really unnecessary. You are trying to determine what 
$$
p\to(q\to p)\tag{1}
$$
is equivalent to. Well, consider this:
\begin{align}
p\to(q\to p) &\equiv \neg p\lor(\neg q\lor p)\tag{$r\to s\equiv \neg r\lor s$}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \underbrace{(\neg p\lor p)}_{\text{always true}}\lor\neg q\tag{associativity of $\lor$}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv T\lor \neg q\\[0.5em]
&\equiv T.
\end{align}
Thus, we can see $(1)$ is a tautology. This means $(1)$ will be logically equivalent to whatever other tautology we come across. Now consider your other two statements, $p\to(p\land q)$ and $p\to(p\lor q)$. Is one of these a tautology? The first one, $p\to(p\land q)$, will not be true when $p$ is true and $q$ is false (so this statement is not a tautology). However, consider the following for the second statement:
\begin{align}
p\to(p\lor q) &\equiv \neg p\lor(p\lor q)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (\neg p\lor p)\lor q\\[0.5em]
&\equiv T\lor q\\[0.5em]
&\equiv T.
\end{align}
Thus, we can easily see, without use of truth tables, that
$$
p\to(q\to p) \equiv p\to(p\lor q).
$$

**Added:** You should note the following:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
p & q & \neg p & \neg p\lor q & p \to q \\ \hline
T & T & F & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & F\\
F & T & T & T & T\\
F & F & T & T & T\\\hline
\end{array}
That is, memorize the equivalence
$$
\Large\color{red}{p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q}
$$
I cannot tell you how many logic/propositional calculus questions I have answered by simple applications of this equivalence. Memorize it. Learn it. Love it. Apply it.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that I learned the wrong implication table.
The correct order for $p\to q$ is:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p&q&p\to q\\\hline
T&F&F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T\\
T&T&T\end{array}$$

Comment: NO, it is misleading to think in terms of order ... the rule is : $p \to q$ is $FALSE$ only when $p$ is $TRUE$ and $q$ is $FALSE$ and it must be so irrespective of the order you choose fot the rows in the t-t. Of course, $p \to q$ is definitely **not** the same as $q \to p$; this one is $FALSE$ only when $q$ is $TRUE$ and $p$ is $FALSE$. The rule is the same, but the results are different...